# Matrix incompatible as CNN input

Tags: matrix, dataset, conv-neural-network, training-data

I'm using now pytorch for image classification from numpy file, I have 2 separated files one for the data and the other for labels, so I applied a split by:  sklearn.model_selection

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True, stratify=labels )
```

The shape of results are:

```
X_train.shape   torch.Size([320, 224, 224, 3])     
X_test.shape   torch.Size([80, 224, 224, 3])
y_train.shape  torch.Size([320])
y_test.shape   torch.Size([80])
```

I reshape X_train and X_test.shape to  ([320, 3, 224, 224]) ,  ([80, 3,224, 224])
Now I want to put these data into AlexNet model (for example) and apply the test to get the accuracy, but I didn't find a good solution!!!
Help me please...

Now I want to put these data into AlexNet model (for example) and apply the test to get the accuracy, but I didn't find a good solution!!!
Help me please...